# Hooking InternetOpenUrl

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, wininet

I am writing an application that should hook `InternetOpenUrl` and `InternetReadFile` in another process.

In the hooked version of `InternetOpenUrl`, it will check whether `lpszUrl` passed to it matches a regular expression. If matches, record the handle returned by the actual `InternetOpenUrl`.

Then in the hooked version of `InternetReadFile`, it will read from a file instead of calling the actual `InternetReadFile` if the `hFile` argument equals to the recorded handle .

I found out that Windows will try to connect to the server provided immediately when calling `InternetOpenUrl` and the function will return `NULL` if failed to establish the connection.

But I want this mechanism to work even without Internet connection, so it seems that I can't get a handle by calling the actual `InternetOpenUrl` in my hooked one when the regular expression matches.

So how can I get it to work?

**UPDATE:**

Now I call `InternetOpen` to get a dummy handle. It seems that handles returned by `InternetOpen` and `InternetOpenUrl` won't equal.

But I'm not sure whether it is guaranteed, looking for better choices.

Comment: It is impossible for an open handle from `InternetOpen` to have the same value as an open handle from `InternetOpenUrl`, because they are both closed by the same function, `InternetCloseHandle`.

Comment: You can't fake the open handle unless you hook all of the other internet functions to recognize the faked handle. You can't mix handle types, the other functions are expecting a real Internet handle.

Comment: @Harry Your comment either has a missing negative or is written wrong, or something, as having the same closing function would imply similarity, not dissimilarity - though certainly doesn't guarantee any sort of cross-compatibility.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think I just need to hook `InternetReadFile` and `InternetOpenUrl` because the target application just uses the handle to download a file. In fact, I've already tried to hook other functions in WinINet to see if other functions are called.

Comment: @Stalker then I suggest having the hooked `InternetOpenUrl()` return a handle from `CreateFile()` for the desired file, and then you can hook `HttpQueryInfo()` to return the file length, hook `InternetReadFile()` to call `ReadFile()`, and hook `InternetCloseHandle()` to call `CloseHandle()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, but the "file://" solution by angorsaxon works and seems to be simpler.

Comment: @angorsaxon: Harry Johnston was using the fact, that handles returned from `InternetOpen` and `InternetOpenUrl` are closed by the same API (`InternetCloseHandle`) to establish, that they are in the namespace. To act as an identifier, handles returned from either call will never collide with handles from the respective other. I don't know if this is the question the OP asked, but if so, then this is the correct answer.

Comment: @angorsaxon: I meant what I wrote and I wrote what I meant. :-)  If two open handles could have the same value, how would `InternetCloseHandle` know which one you wanted to close?

Comment: @Harry Oh, I misunderstood, thought you meant the same type (of handle), not value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are attempting to redirect a URL query to a file... You could always host the file, then you will be guaranteed a valid handle in either scenario. However, assuming a local file, I think if you specify the **"file://"** protocol in the URL it may work in the way you desire.

Comment: The "file://" solution seems great. I didn't know that InternetOpenUrl supports it. I'll try it.

Comment: Oh, bad news... I found out just now that the target application calls `HttpQueryInfo` to get the file length. I don't think "file://" will work on this.

Comment: Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: Damn... My Visual Studio is refusing to work. I have to fix it before I can start again.

Comment: The target process can download the file using "file://"! Thanks you very much! `HttpQueryInfo` doesn't work for now, but I can hook it to get it working.

Comment: The documentation for InternetOpenUrl specifically says that it only accepts `http`, `https`, and `ftp`.  But it might be out of date, I guess.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I am sure they don't recommend it's use for anything else, nor encourage such, so this may not even be intentional, just an incidental side-effect of how the Internet APIs are implemented (sharing code with IE/Edge).